# tableview custom section head view with xib on iphone 6 and 6s

Tags: xcode

### But, head view always cover first cell, and I find the tableHeadview the same to; please help me!

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {

    MTRateCountView *section1HeadView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MTRateCountView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];

    NSLog(@"%f",section1HeadView.size.height);

    return section1HeadView;
}


    return nil;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


if (section == 0) {

      MTRateCountView *section1HeadView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MTRateCountView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
    NSLog(@"%f",section1HeadView.size.height);
    return section1HeadView.size.height;
}


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replace  UITableviewController with UIViewController, and it worked for me!